# What's the difference between setFocusable() and setFocusableWindowState()?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am confused about these 2 APIs:

> java.awt.Component.setFocusable():
>
> Sets the focusable state of this Component to the specified value.
>   This value overrides the Component's default focusability.

And:

> java.awt.Window.setFocusableWindowState():
>
> Sets whether this Window can become the focused Window if it meets the
>   other requirements outlined in isFocusableWindow. If this Window's
>   focusable Window state is set to false, then isFocusableWindow will
>   return false. If this Window's focusable Window state is set to true,
>   then isFocusableWindow may return true or false depending upon the
>   other requirements which must be met in order for a Window to be
>   focusable.

Comment: After all the questions you have asked, its about time you start "accepting" some answers.

Comment: @camickr Sorry, these days are quite busy, I haven't got time to fully respond these answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

`Component.setFocusable()` is for individual components.

`Window.setFocusableWindowState()` is for the entire window. If a window can't be focusable then none of the components can be focusable by default either. This would also be used by the OS. For example, when you use Alt-Tab on Windows to cycle through the windows any window that is not focusable will not be reachable.